# Create a list by importing a .txt file

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
myList = {"later", "test"}
aList = [];
tagCount = {}

f = ["This is a test", "Call me later"]

 for line in f:
 #Get a separate line
    fields = line.split(' ')
    for word in fields:
       if word in myList:
          print(word)
```

It basically checks whether word for word in an array whether one word corresponds to words in the taglist. It works fine. However I would like to replace the myList list now with value I get from .txt file. So there I do:

```
  with open('taglist.txt') as f:
     myList = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
     myList = set(myList)

 aList = [];
 tagCount = {}

 f = ["This is a test", "Call me later"]

 for line in f:
 #Get a separate line
 fields = line.split(' ')
  for word in fields:
   if word in myList:
     print(word)
```

Now it does not seem to work however. I assume something goes wrong with importing the list. Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Comment: `[line.rstrip('\n') for line in f.readlines()]`

Comment: @MMF `.readlines` is unnecessary. @Frits Verstraten What exactly "does not seem to work"?

Comment: I hope you don't have that indentation, because it's incorrect

Comment: @laike9m I do not get any prints and as I have test and Call in my .txt file I assume prints...

Comment: @FritsVerstraten Could you show us the content of your file? And the whole output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code worked for me once I re-indented it :

```
with open('taglist.txt') as tl:
  myList = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in tl]
  myList = set(myList)

aList = [];
tagCount = {}

f = ["This is a test", "Call me later"]

for line in f:
#Get a separate line
  fields = line.split(' ')
  for word in fields:
    if word in myList:
      print(word)
```

taglist.txt

```
later 
test
```

Comment: Yes, but you declare f later on line 9. 
f = ["This is a test", "Call me later"]. Does it also work when comment that out?

Comment: It was correct - your confusing the code by re-using f but it does work

Comment: Changed initial f to tl for clarity